# VueJS dependent properties

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

There is a form with 3 fields,

1. Total Item (QTY)
2. UNIT Price (Single Item)
3. Total Price (All Items)

The scenario is like this, user will enter Total Item along with one other value, either unit price or total price, 
if user enter unit price, I have to calculate total price by multiplying total item into unit price, 
if user enter total price, I have to divide it by total item and get the unit price.

I am trying to achieve it with including unit price and total price in `watch` without success, here is my code,

```
  watch:{
        unit_rate: function(newVal){
            if(newVal != ''){
                this.total_rate = parseInt(this.total_item) * parseFloat(newVal);
            }else{
                this.total_rate = '';
            }
        },
        total_rate: function(newVal){
            if(newVal != ''){
                this.unit_rate = parseFloat(newVal) / parseInt(this.total_item);
            }else{
                this.unit_rate = '';
            }
        }
    },
```

I am not sure whether I can modify the property like this while both of them are already in the observe. I did not get the expected output as well, something wrong,,

Comment: I think you might have an infinite loop. When `unit_rate == ''` you set `total_rate = ''` and the same in the reverse way. For this case, I would use computed properties instead.

Comment: I think the same, i might have infinite execution, do you have an idea how to solve this in the same form fields even if i use computed fields